# Как работает Elementor и WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Часто можно увидеть на сайтах как Themeforest, что тема для вордпресс сделана с Elementor. У вордпресс есть доступная документация для тех кто хочет создавать сайты на нём. Но у элементора только справочник для создания плагинов для самого элементора.

Вопрос в этом: как создают темы с элементором? Как мне кажется разработчики тем для начала натягивают или создают верстку на вордпресс и потом делают его доступным для элементора. Или они с нуля без php кода делают верстку уже в элементоре?

Comment: Не "тема вордпресс сделана с Elementor", а "тема поддерживает Elementor". Это чистейшей воды развод. Любая тема будет поддерживать любой пейджбилдер.
Но нормальные темы из оф каталога и сами по себе функциональны, а вот большинство тем с Themeforest без пейджбилдеров убоги и без них темы практически невозможно использовать. Т.е. редко какие самодостаточны.

Comment: спасибо за ответ!